# When should I train my own models and when should I use pretrained models?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

Is it recommended to train my own models for things like sentiment analysis, despite only having a very small dataset (5000 reviews), or is it best to use pretrained models which were trained on way larger datasets, however aren't "specialized" on my data.

Also, how could I train my model on my data and then later use it on it too? I was thinking of an iterative approach where the training data would be randomly selected subset of my total data for each learning epoch.

Comment: Unless its a problem where your data is very specific, its best to use pretrained models. Pretrained models should be your default. For anything NLP related, always best to try pretrained models first, and then fine tuning them. If that fails, then you can attempt to train something from scratch.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which is about *specific programming* questions; please see the NOTE in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/artificial-intelligence/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go like this:

- Try the pre-trained model and see how it goes
- If results are non satisfactory, you can [fine tune](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/transfer-learning-for-nlp-fine-tuning-bert-for-text-classification/) it (see [this tutorial](https://huggingface.co/transformers/training.html)). Basically, you are using your own examples to change the weights of the pre-trained model. This should improve the results, but it depends on how your data is and how many examples you can provide. The more you have, the better it should be (I would try to use 10-20k at least)

> Also, how could I train my model on my data and then later use it on it too?

Be careful to distinguish between *pre-train* *and fine-tuning*.

For pre-training you need a **huge** amount of text (like billions of characters), it is very resource demanding, and tipically you don't want to do that, unless for a very good reason (for example, a model for your target language does not exist).

Fine-tuning requires much much less examples (some tents of thousands), it take tipycally less than a day on a single GPU and allow you to exploit pre-trained model created by someone else.

From what you write, I would go with fine-tune.

Of course you can save the model for later, as you can see in the tutorial I linked above:

```
model.save_pretrained("my_imdb_model")
```

Comment: Thank you, sir. :)

Oh btw, I think you misunderstood me. My question was not about saving the model, I know how to do that. The question was how I could train and deploy a model on the same dataset. Since I only have 5000 reviews, slicing it into a training set and a set which I will actually use, seems silly.

So, I want to train on Dataset A and then also use my model to extract Data from Dataset A without falling victim to some inherent bias,or overfitting or whatever. :)